# Simplify factorials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question is a piece of a larger one from Special Functions.

Simplify 
$$n^2[\sqrt\pi\cdot 2^{n-1}\cdot(n-1)!]+\frac14[\sqrt\pi\cdot 2^{n+1}\cdot(n+1)!]$$

My basic math is extremely rusty and this is giving me a hard time. Any help is greatly appreciated.

(I apologize for the equation formatting)

Comment: How to format equations so that they're readable can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you, I will review this before posting in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$n^{ 2 }[\sqrt { \pi  } \cdot 2^{ n-1 }\cdot (n-1)!]+\frac { 1 }{ 4 } [\sqrt { \pi  } \cdot 2^{ n+1 }\cdot (n+1)!]=n[\sqrt { \pi  } \cdot 2^{ n-1 }\cdot n!]+\left[ \sqrt { \pi  } \cdot 2^{ n-1 }\cdot (n+1)! \right] \\ =\sqrt { \pi  } { 2 }^{ n-1 }n!\left[ n+\left( n+1 \right)  \right] =\left( 2n+1 \right) n!{ 2 }^{ n-1 }\sqrt { \pi  }  $$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$ 2^{n+1}=4\cdot 2^{n-1}$$
and $$(n+1)!=(n+1)\cdot n\cdot (n-1)!$$